# Android - Android 6.0 - Application process - Service process

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-debug

I'm working on an android application providing a service.

I'd like to have the application and the service running on one process.

My manifest:

```
<application
    android:process="@string/my_process"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        ...
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".core.MessengerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process="@string/my_process" >
        <intent-filter>
            ...
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    ...

</application>
```

But when I debug step by step my application on an Android 6.0 device, I get the freezing message "Application is waiting for the debugger to attach `@my_progress` ...". (This problem does not occur on my Android 4.4 device)

And when I seperate the application and the service into 2 different proccesses, the debug works properly on my Android 6.0 device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to have the application and the service running on one process.

Then get rid of all `android:process` attributes in your manifest. The default is that all components run in a single process.

> And when I seperate the application and the service into 2 different proccesses

That does not happen. An `Application` singleton is created in every process.

Comment: So if I declare my service process with an other name, my application and my service are still sharing the same process?

Comment: I want to share my object between the application and the service.

Comment: @Anh-TuanMai: "my application and my service are still sharing the same process?" -- the process containing your service will contain an instance of your `Application` singleton. Any other process that your app uses will *also* contain an instance of your `Application` singleton. Every process used by your app will contain an instance of your `Application` singleton.

Comment: How the object is shared between processes?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev I have a singleton class `Core`, if my application is launched I have an instance of `Core`, but my service uses an other instance of `Core` -> KO. My service and my application activities (which can be lauched on foreground by user/other apps) must always run on one process.

Comment: @Anh-TuanMai: "My service and my application activities (which can be lauched on foreground by user/other apps) must always run on one process" -- then, as I wrote, remove all `android:process` attributes in your manifest. The default behavior is for all application components to run within one process.